# Flash compile error - Definition *** could not be found

Tags: flash, import

This is my first project in Flash and I've run under problems.
I have downloaded some code and when I try to build it I get an error:

```
Error: Definition flash.globalization:LocaleID could not be found.

        import flash.globalization.LocaleID;
```

How do I locate/add this missing thing/package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have found it:

> To do that in FB, you need to go to the Properties of the project, select ActionScript Compiler and 
>   make it to use 10.1.0 for the Flash Player... The default is set to 10.0.0, so just change it to **10.1.0** and you should be able to import flash.globalization package...

source: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=250709&page=2

Comment: revised source: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/flex-2-3-and-4-a/250709-cant-import-flash-globalization-package.html